# How to get margin auto size using javascript when I use margin auto property in css

Tags: javascript, html, css, margin

I have a `svg` with `margin:auto;` is it possible to get the value of the margin auto so I can use it in my webapp?

```
#svg {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```
<svg id = "svg" width = "850" height = "800"></svg>
```

Comment: your question is not clear. pls give more explanation of what you want to achieve

Comment: How can I find the margin sizes after using margin auto?

Comment: do you need to know the size of `margin: auto` relative to the parent container?